# Complete IPv4 Address Space

Tags: text

I know this was asked before, but I didn't get a definitive answer. I am trying to download a simple 17GB .txt file that contains the entire IPv4 address space. There must be a file like this already on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply generate them yourself. They are simply representations of all integers up to $2^{32}$

Which format do you want the address? [There are many ways to represent them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_space_exhaustion) according to your requirements, due to the fact that they are simply representation of a set of normal numbers:

- standard dot-separated e.g. 192.168.0.1
- unsigned int32 : e.g 3548551264
- hex, dotted hex, octal bytes

---

You could generate them in Python like this:

```
def generate_ips(): 
    """Generate all possible IPv4 addresses, on by one""" 
    for i in range(255): 
        for j in range(255):
            for k in range(255):
                for l in range(255):
                    yield "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}".format(i, j, k, l)
```

The you must loop on the generator function like this to actuall use the values:

```
for ip in generate_ips(): 
    print(ip) 

# output
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2
0.0.0.3
0.0.0.4
0.0.0.5
0.0.0.6
0.0.0.7
```

I used a generator (with the `yield` keyword instead of saving all values in a list) because it will just give you one at a time and not consume all those Gb of memory that you mentioned!

If you want to store all values in a list for some reason, you can alter the function to append each IP address to a list, then return that:

```
def generate_ips():
    """Return a list of all possible IPv4 addresses"""
    all_ips = []
    for i in range(255):
        for j in range(255):
            for k in range(255):
                for l in range(255):
                    ip = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}".format(i, j, k, l)
                    all_ips.append(ip)
    return all_ips
```

Comment: Could we move this to chat for you to show me out to store them all in a list?

Comment: Are these two separate python files?

Comment: @C.Rutscher - I have added a simple list version. You can put the functions in the same file (give them different function names after `def`) and just run whichever one you need.

Comment: How do I output it to a .txt file though?

Comment: @C.Rutscher - Have alook for a tutorial [(like this one)](https://cmdlinetips.com/2012/09/three-ways-to-write-text-to-a-file-in-python/) online somewhere. There are lots!